# Negative odd number in c++

Tags: c++

```
        #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int arr[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,-7,8,-9,10};

  int checkNeg = 0;

  for(int i =0; i <10; i++){
     if((arr[i] < 0) && ((arr[i] % 2)  == 1) ){
        checkNeg++;
     }
  }
cout << checkNeg;
}
```

Why am I getting 0? I am trying to write program which will print number of negative odd numbers.

Comment: tl;dr on the dup: The result of `%` matches the sign of the dividend, so if you want a value that's always positive, do `(a % b + b) % b`.

Comment: Have you tried debugging to see what `arr[i] % 2` is?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo `if (arr[i] < 0 && arr[i] % 2 == -1)` is simpler